# Networking IPv4 exercise

Tags: networking, routes, ip-address, subnet, switching

I’m starting to learn about networking. It would be really helpful a bit of help with this exercise and some explanations, cause I’m really stuck.

This is the network topology  from the exercise:

[image: Topology from exercise]

### We know about it:

1. AP1, AP2 and AP3 work as bridges between their wireless and ethernet interfaces (br0)
2. R1 job is the routing of interfaces
3. Private IPv4 addressing is used [192.168.X.X] (only not for F1)
4. Each network must grant Internet access to 450 hosts at least (only not for F1)
5. The “br0” interfaces must be accessible by IP from every device in any of the internal nets

### Questions:

1. Which mode (Infrastructure, Ad-hoc, WDS) should the Wifi connections use between AP1-AP2 and which one between AP3-R1? **(done)**
2. Fill this tables with the IP directions (IpDir/Mask CIDR Format) that would grant Internet access to every device.

### IPv4 interfaces directions

| Device | Interface | IPv4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **PC10** | eth0 |  |
| **PC11** | eth0 |  |
| **PC12** | eth0 |  |
| **M1** | wlan0 |  |
| **AP1** | br0 |  |
| **AP2** | br0 |  |
| **AP3** | br0 |  |
| **R1** | eth0 |  |
| **R1** | wlan0 |  |
| **F1** | eth0 |  |
| **F1** | fa0 | 11.17.1.30/30 |

### Routing tables

**R1**

| Destiny | Next jump |
| --- | --- |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |

**F1**

| Destiny | Next jump |
| --- | --- |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |

**AP1**

| Destiny | Next jump |
| --- | --- |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |

**AP2**

| Destiny | Next jump |
| --- | --- |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |

**AP3**

| Destiny | Next jump |
| --- | --- |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |
| _ | _ |

### Default gateways

| Device | Default Gateway |
| --- | --- |
| **PC10** |  |
| **PC11** |  |
| **PC12** |  |
| **M1** |  |
| **R1** |  |
| **F1** |  |
| **AP1** |  |
| **AP2** |  |
| **AP3** |  |

For 2nd question, that's where I have the biggest problem, I'm not sure if I need to create 3 subnets or 4, cause of the wireless router on R1 that gives connection to M1 terminal.
I assume that they follow the private directions schema, 192.168.X.X So since we need to give connection to 450 hosts, we can use:

1. 192.168.0.0/24
2. 192.168.64.0/24
3. 192.168.128.0/24
4. 192.168.192.0/24

Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

I want to say sorry because I can't give on the comment section cause of lacking reputation and my grammar is bad.

Number 1 question : It clearly doesn't use Ad-hoc cause it has AP and routers. So your choice is only infra and WDS. I will use WDS on AP1-AP2, and Infrastructure on Ap3-R1

Explanation :

- AD-hoc / peer to peer mode doesn't rely on some infrastructure such as AP or routers. It is formed from groups of wireless users. For example : your PC with your partner's PC. U can exchange any data without any routers or AP.
- Infra mode : Infrastructure mode is a wireless network framework that has a central WLAN access point / router at the heart of the network. In infrastructure mode, wireless devices communicate with each other through an WLAN access point/router. (from https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=ads2500w_us&faqid=faq00002194_000). On the picture, this connection require a centralized AP which is AP3 to connect to the internet. The AP3 is so important cause it is the only way to have Internet connection.
- WDS : U can read it from here. This is the explanation of why I choose WDS. https://www.cisco.com/assets/sol/sb/AP541N_Emulators/AP541N_Emulator_v1.9.2/help_WDS_Bridge.htm

And for question number 2, does we only know about 1 IP which is Internet default gateway (11.17.1.29/30)? So fa0 on F1 will have 11.17.1.30/30. How about internal network IP Block? Do we have to assign it randomly or there are IP blocks that stated on your questions?

Comment: A lot of thanks for that very complete answer! I understood it perfectly all.
For 2nd question, that's where I have the biggest problem, I'm not sure if I need to create 3 subnets or 4, cause of the wireless router on R that gives connection to M1 terminal.

Comment: For the IP directions, I assume that they follow the private dirs.schema, 192.168.X.X
So since we need to give connection to 450 hosts, we can use: 192.168.0.X ; 192.168.64.X ; 192.168.128.X ; 192.168.192. Isn't it?

Comment: If your assumption says so, I will follow it.
The first requirement is 450 hosts so u can't take /24 because it only can take up to 254 hosts. U need at least /23 to make it work because it can take up to 510 hosts. Then u can start doing your VLSM / subnetting calculation. 
If you have done it, I recommend u to use packet tracer or something like that to make sure that your config is correct. Good Luck :)

(got edited cause I don't read the AP could receive hosts too)